# Priority of razor views over the aspx in mixed MVC3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've converted old MVC2 project to MVC3. Now I have .aspx views along with razor .cshtml.

Let's say I have a view associated with controller (`HomeController`, `Index` action and `~\Views\Home\Index.aspx`) and at the same time I still have absolutely different  `~\Views\Shared\Index.aspx`.

Normally when `Index` Action calls `View()` it renders `~\Views\Home\Index.aspx`. But if I convert the view into razor view, the same action instead of rendering `~\Views\Home\Index.cshtml` calls 
`~\Views\Shared\Index.aspx`.

So I guess MVC gives priority to .aspx pages rather to .cshtml. Maybe I need to change something in web.config files, because now I have to explicitly tell it which view to get:

```
View("~\Views\Home\Index.cshtml")
```

Even if I drop the extension `View("~\Views\Home\Index")` it will still call the shared .aspx view, although I have the right path. Strange isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are having is the default priority of MVC views.  Here is the default:

```
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

As you can see, it favors all aspx/ascx files, even in the shared directory, before similar razor views.

One solution is to [Get MVC Razor favor .cshtml over .aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434015/get-mvc-razor-favor-cshtml-over-aspx), **however this solution does NOT reassociated the aspx/ascx files**. So you'd need something like:

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{ 
  ViewEngines.Engines.Clear(); 
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine()); 
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine()); 
}
```

Comment: Now the only small issue here: if you have resharper installed and try to open associated view from the controller, it still will be pointing to the shared View. Although Visual Studio's "Go to View" will open the correct one

Comment: Sounds like you should let resharper know the bug, cause that is definitely a bug.