# Call Partial Aspx inside razor MVC3 page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i want to call partial ReportViewer.aspx from a page in MVC3 project but the partial cant find the location and show an error like this
how can i resolve it?

[Error location didn't show .aspx location in all path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mFXC.png)

the global asax route of my project :

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");  
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "ISpace.Controllers" }
);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after researching in google and i got this link from  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336677/priority-of-razor-views-over-the-aspx-in-mixed-mvc3-project) it solve my question, i should register viewengine for webform and razor. 
here is the code from that link

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can setting in router config:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Test", "Test/{Controller}/{ActionName}", "~/Views/{Controller}/{ActionName}.aspx");
```